# Set of dominoes going up to eight or nine?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Here is a problem from my probability textbook:

> It is not known whether a set of dominoes goes to double eight or double nine, each being equally likely. Two dominoes are drawn and found to contain no number higher than eight. Show that the odds are now three to two in favor of the set going only to double eight.

However, what I get as the probabilities of the set going to double eight and double nine, respectively:$${{{1\over2}\times 1}\over{{1\over2} \times 1 + {1\over2} \times {7\over{11}}}} = {{11}\over{18}}, \quad {{{1\over2}\times {7\over{11}}}\over{{1\over2} \times 1 + {1\over2} \times {7\over{11}}}} = {{7}\over{18}},$$so instead of the desired odds of three to two, we have eleven to seven. So what did I do wrong? Or is the book wrong?

**Edit:** Where some of the terms above come from: There's probability $1$ we draw two dominoes with no number higher than eight if the set gets to double eight, and there's probability ${{\binom{36}{2}}\over{\binom{45}{2}}} = {7\over{11}}$ we draw two dominoes with no number higher than eight if the set gets to double nine.

Comment: It appears one needs to know what sets of dominoes consist of.

Comment: I believe you are forgetting blank faces.  As i understand it (and I may well be incorrect), a domino set that goes to double $N$ has $a_N=\frac {N(N+1)}2+N+1$ tiles.  Thus $a_8=45$ and $a_9=55$.  The $a_9$ number appears to be confirmed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominoes).   In any case, my numbers give the official answer.

Comment: A set of dominoes contains one of each pair $0\le m \le n \le N$, for some fixed $N$.  So a double-nine set has $55$ tiles, of which $10$ show a nine.  Does that help?